# How to change opacity of multiple elements with scrolling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The effect I'm trying to achieve can be seen here: http://sfcd.com/

Specifically in the "works" section.

I can see scrolling changes the opacity for the colored background divs.

My question is, how can that be achieved with jquery?

Do i simply do this for each div? Is there a way to achieve it all in one jquery function instead of using this function 3 times with different class selectors? Would this function even work to achieve the effect similar to the site linked above?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.home__works_bg_blue').css({
    opacity: function() {
      var elementHeight = $(this).height();
      return 1 - (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you could add a specific class for this purpose and write the jquery function once around it